What is $\mathrm{Hom}_{F[\mathbf A]}(V,V)$ in terms of matrices?
I am learning linear alegrbra and was confused by a notation in a theorem.
Here is the theorem in the textbook:

Suppose $\mathbf A$ is a linear transformation on vector space $V$ over field $F$, and the minimal polynomial of $\mathbf A$ is $m(\lambda)=p(\lambda)$ where $p(\lambda)$ is an irreducable polynomial on field $F$, $\deg p(\lambda)=r$. Then $C(\mathbf A)=\mathrm{Hom}_{F[\mathbf A]}(V,V)$,$\dim_FC(\mathbf A)=\frac1r(\dim_FV)^2$.

where $C(\mathbf A)$ is the set of all linear transformations commutative with $\mathbf A$.
The textbook has proven before that $F[\mathbf A]$ is a field when the minimal polynomial of $\mathbf A$ is irriducable, and $V$ can be regarded as a vector space over $F[\mathbf A]$. So $\mathrm{Hom}_{F[\mathbf A]}(V,V)$ does make sense.
However, when I tried to find $C(A)$ for a specific matrix $A$, I did not know how to work out  $\mathrm{Hom}_{F[\mathbf A]}(V,V)$ in terms of a matrices. I did not even know what kind of things should be put into the matrices (elements of $F$ or $F[\mathbf A]$?). In other words, how can I get the basis matrices of $C(A)$?

The simplest nontrivial example, which will be good to understand thoroughly to build intuition, is the following. Take $F = \mathbb{R}, V = \mathbb{R}^2$, and
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
to be the $90^{\circ}$ rotation. The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $t^2 + 1 = 0$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$. So the field $\mathbb{R}[A] \cong \mathbb{R}[t]/(t^2 + 1) \cong \mathbb{C}$ generated by $A$ is the complex numbers. Now the centralizer $C(A)$ is, explicitly,
$$C(A) = \{ X \in M_2(\mathbb{R}) : XA = AX \}$$
(in particular we are still only considering matrices over $F$, not over $F[A]$). In this case you can compute explicitly that $C(A) \cong \mathbb{R}[A]$ (in other words, $\mathbb{R}[A]$ is self-centralizing), so that $C(A)$ is $2$-dimensional with basis $\{ 1, A \}$.

$F[A]$ is a commutative ring and $V$ has a natural structure of a $F[A]$-module. $\text{Hom}_{F[A]}(V,V)$ is the set of endomorphisms of $V$, seen as this $F[A]$-module, i.e. the set of maps $V\to V$ which are $F[A]$-linear.
Explicitely, the module structure is given by :
$$\forall n\in\mathbb N,\forall a_0,\ldots,a_n \in F, \forall x\in V,(a_nA^n+ \ldots +a_1 A +a_0)\cdot x = a_n A^n(x) + \ldots + a_1 A(x) + a_0x $$
It is easy to see that a map $\phi:V\to V$ is $F[A]$-linear if, and only if, it is $F$-linear and commutes with $A$.
